# Pourquoi Des Grieux dit-il « un autre lit que moi » et non « un autre lit que le mien » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, comparatifs, pronoms-personnels, possessif

Dans le roman « Histoire du Chevalier des Grieux et de Manon Lescaut », Des Grieux dit à Manon :

> Je ne parle point à présent des alarmes où votre fuite imprévue m’a jeté, ni de la cruauté que vous avez eue de m’abandonner sans un mot de consolation, *après avoir passé la nuit dans un autre lit que moi*.

Pourquoi dit-il « un autre lit que moi » et non « un autre lit que le mien » ? Je crois que la comparaison est entre « un autre lit » et celui de Des Grieux, non Des Grieux lui-même, donc on doit utiliser « le mien ». Est-ce que c'est une locution familière ou vieillie ?

Je vois qu'il y a [une édition](https://books.google.com/books?id=SCpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22un%20autre%20lit%20que%20le%20mien%22%20%22manon%20lescaut%22&source=bl&ots=096VFphPW9&sig=ACfU3U3veXLz7NWraPP20uqJT0cHAS63ng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtuP2ewMvoAhVKbs0KHUlFCb0Q6AEwAHoECAoQKQ#v=onepage&q=%22un%20autre%20lit%20que%20le%20mien%22%20%22manon%20lescaut%22&f=false) de « Manon Lescaut » où le rédacteur a remplacé « moi » par « le mien ».

Comment: Le phrasé ne me choque pas du tout, c'est interprétable comme "dans un autre lit que celui dans lequel j'ai **moi** passé la nuit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*L'Histoire du Chevalier des Grieux et de Manon Lescaut* a paru en 1731, une nouvelle édition revue et corrigée par l'auteur est sortie en 1753.  Prévost précisait dans la préface de la nouvelle édition :

« C'est pour se rendre aux instances de ceux qui aiment ce petit ouvrage, qu'on s'est déterminé à le purger d'un grand nombre de fautes grossières qui se sont glissées dans la plupart des éditions.  On y a fait aussi quelques additions qui ont paru nécessaires pour la plénitude d'un des principaux caractères. »

Malgré cela, on lit dans les deux éditions : « … après avoir passé la nuit dans un autre lit que moi. »  « … que le mien » est donc une correction qui n'est pas due à Prévost, qui n'était pas choqué par la phrase d'origine au point de vouloir la modifier.

L'une des raisons à cela est que le style du premier XVIIIe siècle ou celui du XVIIe siècle, pour rester dans l'époque moderne, permet l'emploi de constructions syntaxiques beaucoup plus relâchées et libres qu'actuellement.  On pense à Saint-Simon, un des grands prosateurs de la langue française, dont l'écriture à la diable et au fil de la plume est souvent *stricto sensu* incorrecte ou avant lui à Pascal dont nombre des *Pensées* s'écartent de la correction grammaticale telle qu'on l'entend aujourd'hui, comme dans :

« Le sentiment de la fausseté des plaisirs présents et l'ignorance de la vanité des plaisirs absents **cause** l'inconstance. »

Pour revenir à Prévost, l'idée est parfaitement compréhensible : j'ai passé la nuit dans un lit, vous avez passé la nuit dans un autre lit, donc, vous avez passé la nuit dans un autre lit que moi. On pourrait être tenté de dire que le caractère débridé de la syntaxe de la phrase s'accorde bien avec le trouble de Des Grieux et « l'alarme » dans laquelle il a été jeté, mais c'est peut-être interpréter les choses de manière anachronique.  En tous cas, l'expression en 1731 n'est pas familière ; elle n'est vieillie maintenant que dans la mesure où elle est typique du français de l'époque.

Answer (score 1):

Pour développer le commentaire d'Eau qui dort que je partage, la correction, en introduisant une petite ambiguïté, ne respecte pas le texte original, même si on peut reprocher à ce dernier une petite liberté avec la logique grammaticale.

> ...après avoir passé la nuit dans un autre lit que moi.

signifie :

> ...après avoir passé la nuit ailleurs que dans le lit où j'ai moi-même passé la nuit.

alors que :

> ...après avoir passé la nuit dans un autre lit que le mien.

peut ne signifier que :

> ...après avoir passé la nuit dans un autre lit que celui qui m'appartient.

La nuance étant donc que Des Grieux n'a pas forcément passé la nuit dans ce lit, même si cette interprétation n'est pas vraiment plausible dans ce passage puisqu'il parle d'abandon.

On peut par exemple comparer :

> Tu es dans un autre pays que moi.
>
> Tu es dans un autre pays que le mien.